# Curious about the wording of my salary in the offer letter - what does "annualizes to a rate" mean?

Tags: salary, job-offer

I negotiated with my firm and received an offer of $91,000 per year.

The only issue I have was that, upon reviewing my offer, I am not sure it adds up precisely.

In my offer letter is says my salary is -  "At a biweekly rate of $3,500.00 which annualizes to approximately $91,000.00"

however, $3500 * 24 = $84,000.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: In fact, you are getting 91k for 364 days, so the annual salary is 1/365 higher than that, another $255.62

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be based on a minor confusion about how many weeks are in a year.

Comment: Note: "biweekly", as the name indicates, means "once every two weeks", not "twice a month", and there are about 52 weeks in a year.

Comment: the [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/biweekly) website defines "biweekly" as "produced or happening every two weeks or twice each week". So it has two meanings :D

Comment: Biweekly means twice a week where I'm from (UK), but I assume that's not the case here or your annual salary would be $364,000. Probably why they put the approximate annual salary there!

Comment: @mattumotu Yes, biweekly has a long-standing ambiguity but I took it as every 2 weeks. OP took it as twice a month which I've never heard before...

Comment: @lucidbrot But neither of those meanings is "twice each month". And if they meant "twice each week" he would expect a total of 3500 * 102 = $357,000, which is not even close to the negotiated salary.

Comment: I don't know why anyone uses "bimonthly" to mean "semi-monthly" or "twice-monthly" (which is plain English and no additional syllables). Meanwhile, here in the UK, we use the term "fortnightly" to mean "every two weeks", which is definitely not the same as twice-monthly.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> In my offer letter is says my salary is - "At a biweekly rate of
> $3,500.00 which annualizes to approximately $91,000.00"
>
> however, $3500 * 24 = $84,000. Am I missing something here?

There are 26 biweekly periods, so 26 * $3,500 = $91,000.

This is an understandable confusion. It seems to make sense to divide a monthly stated salary in half when discussing a biweekly salary. The confusion also happens when benefits like insurance premiums are stated with an annual or monthly number, but pay is biweekly.

Answer (score 5):

There are 365 days in a year*.

There are (365/7)/2 = 26.071 bi-weekly periods in a year.

$91000/26.071 = $3490.468

So yes, you are missing something here.

$3500*26.071 - $91000 = $248.50

You're getting $248.50 more per annum.

<sup>*there are approx 365.25, but let's ignore leap years..</sup>

Comment: Where does the figure of $ 248.50 come from?

Comment: I get a difference of exactly $250 when using a year with 365 days.

Comment: Yeah, $3,500 per two-week period is exactly $250 per calendar day, and a common year is 52 weeks plus one day, so you get an extra $250 per common year and an extra $500 per leap year.

Comment: In practice it is more like you get an extra $3500 every 11.2 years, isn't it?

Comment: @CodesInChaos see added content regarding extra calculation

Comment: @Tanner Swett 91000/365= 249.315. I'm not sure where $250 comes from ?

Comment: $91000 / 364 days = $3500 / 14 days = $250 per day, precisely. So you end up with $91250 for 365 days. I think your mistake was rounding (365/7)/2 = 26.071, if you use more decimals the result should be correct.

Comment: But there aren't 364 days in a year, there are 365. If that's how they'll pay them, then effectivity they're not accounting for one day and artificially bloating the pay.

Comment: I was using the google keypad on iOS to get these numbers, I hadn't realised it was rounding... I'll have to check once I get to something more accurate.

Comment: "annualizes to *approximately* $91,000.00", it looks like they used 26 payment periods of 14 days each for that.

Comment: They get paid $3,500 every 14 calendar days, which is an average of $250 per calendar day, which is the same as $91,250 per 365 calendar days. So, the amount they get paid in an average 365 calendar day period (namely, $91,250) is exactly $250 greater than what they were "supposed to" get (namely, $91,000).

Comment: But don't forget they also *worked* that extra day ('on average').

Comment: My thinking is based on what I learned here: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/135798/company-using-4-week-months-in-my-salary-calculation-are-they-undercutting-me. I only have my memory and an iPhone to work with currently (no paper and pen) so I'm not 100% sure my math is correct, but FWIW something still seems incorrect about $250 ‍♂️.